# Writing a custom function under the Mathlib (nmath) library

Tags: r, c, nmath, mathlib

I would like to modify a Mathlib function (into a different one) and use it from R.

The function has many Mathlib dependencies.
Currently, I access these functions via R's core packages using `:::`.
One option is to include the `nmath` library in a custom R package.
What's the best way to achieve this?

Thank you,
Gilad

Comment: Welcome To SO! I'm not sure I entirely understand your question (maybe you can clarify with some examples) but I assume you've read the advice in the "Note" section of the help file for `:::`: `?\`:::\``

Comment: Thanks. 
I would like to add a custom C function to (a local) Mathlib and use it from R. The `:::` is not the issue here, it's how I've been accessing the C functions.